# Creating Styled component with multiple elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I am dabbling with [Styled components](https://styled-components.com/), and was trying to create a "dumb" component which has multiple html tags in it. Something like:

```
<div className="component-container">
  <a href="#some-link">Link text</a>
  <p className="para">Some Text</p>
</div>
```

Is there a way to wrap above html in one single styled component? I read the documentation, and I only see examples of single html element based components like this:

```
const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

  .para { 
    font-size: 15px;
   }
`;
```

I know I can do:

```
<Container>
  <a href="#some-link">Link text</a>
  <p className="para">Some Text</p>
</Container>
```

But that won't be optimal. I would rather create a normal React functional component instead, which can wrap all the markup in one single component which I can import anywhere and use in a single line.

Comment: Consider you have created styled component like that. But then where `children` of that component will be rendered. Inside main `div` , `a` or `p`. I don't think styled component is made for combining elements. Better to use a react component.

Comment: You read the API, you can't do it

Comment: I am a bit disappointed by this. This means that we will often have to resort to normal functional components, meaning that not all of our code will get the benefits of styled components like css scoping and ease of managing css across components. So we will still need to implement other css scoping techniques. So not super useful for big projects I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The way you would code something like this is make it a functional component like you are saying.

```
const YourComponent = () => (
    <Container>
        <a href="#some-link">Link text</a>
        <p className="para">Some Text</p>
    </Container>
);
```

Styled-components only style elements, but the Container styled-component can be re-used of course.